# selenium click by id python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[Web page inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQie.png)

I want to make the bot click on WhatsApp
I tried this, but it didn't work for me:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'WhatsApp')]").click()
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: please Edit the question and provide The Error you get

Comment: Please provide **All** your code, the single code line you provided is not enough here.

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath -> driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"").click()

Comment: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document